# Word to describe seemingly opposing terms

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the feeling of being over- and underwhelmed at the same time?

This oftentimes comes up work when I am faced with a task that seems simultaneously monumental and mundane. As in "This project of editing 10,000 outdated contacts has me feeling _________".

I have considered using exhasperated, hopeless, bored to tears, but none of those quite capture the essence of both words.

Comment: From the [single-word-requests tag description](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info): _To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used._  Also, what words have you considered and why didn't they work for you?   You might want to check out the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) as well.

Answer (score 1):

[**Conflicted**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflicted)

> - experiencing or marked by ambivalence or a conflict especially of emotions
> - having or showing feelings that disagree with one another

*This project of editing 10,000 outdated contacts has me feeling conflicted*